# SQL Server 2016 - Can't to log into SSMS after install

Tags: sql-server

I recently installed MS SQL Server 2016 Standard on a Windows 2016 Server.

I used the local Administrator account to do the install. I did not select mixed mode during the installation, so there is no 'sa' account, the only account that has permission to access SQL Server is the local computer's Administrator account (named Administrator). I know the administrator password, I can log into the server just fine with it. After installing SQL Server I then installed SSMS and tried to log in. I am using "Windows Authentication" and clicking "Connect" and getting the following error:

```
===================================

Cannot connect to COMPUTERNAME.

===================================

Login failed for user 'COMPUTERNAME\Administrator'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=18456&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Server Name: COMPUTERNAME
Error Number: 18456
Severity: 14
State: 1
Line Number: 65536
```

When I check the error log file for SQL I see this:

```
2018-12-07 16:23:33.79 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
2018-12-07 16:23:33.79 Logon       Login failed for user 'COMPUTERNAME\Administrator'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
```

There are two possible problems I can think of.

1. The computer's actual computer name is COMPUTER_NAME and somehow it looks like the underscores were dropped when SQL was installed. However, I have a second server working just fine and it has an underscore in the computer name. I can log into SSMS even without the underscore in the Server Name or Account Name on the other server.
2. I somehow selected a different account than 'Administrator' to install SQL under. Is there any way (other than logging into SSMS which I can't do) to check this?

Most recommendations online I see are to verify you are using Windows Authentication (I am) or to log into SSMS and verify the account info (which I can't do).

Comment: fire up the installation again and note the section where the user ids are set

Comment: [Connect to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: It seems like you are trying to login with Wrong login name.. So you need to create the login 'COMPUTERNAME\Administrator' or a login for a windows group it is a member of... As you mentioned try with "COMPUTER_NAME\Adminstrator", if you still facing connection errors update in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:  Looks like I installed SQL under DOMAIN\Administrator instead of COMPUTERNAME\Administrator.

Logging into the server as the domain account Administrator resolved the issue.